# Regex match 2 letters and up to 10 digits afterwards

Tags: regex

I have the following regex which is matching the first 2 letters `RR` and then 4 numbers after.

```
RR[0-9]{4}
```

How can I change it to detect the first 2 letters `RR` and then up to 10 digits afterwards?

I know I can do...

```
^[0-9]*$
```

To match all numbers but how can I limit this and add it to the first regex?

Comment: try `RR\d{10}` ..

Comment: Also, here is a [relevant video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rM7gfA9j-L4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RR\d{0,10}`. This matches `RR`, followed by 0 to 10 digits, i.e. up to 10 digits.